# append datetime object to list, group by shape

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code:

```
from datetime import datetime

values = [[datetime(2017, 1, 22, 10, 2, 11, 170913), datetime(2017, 1, 22, 10, 3, 11, 170913), 
           datetime(2017, 1, 2, 10, 4, 11, 170913), datetime(2017, 1, 22, 10, 5, 11, 170913)],
          [datetime(2017, 1, 22, 10, 1, 11, 170913), datetime(2017, 1, 22, 10, 2, 11, 170913), 
           datetime(2017, 1, 22, 10, 3, 11, 170913), datetime(2017, 1, 22, 10, 4, 11, 170913)]]

secs = []
secs.append([i.timestamp() for t in values for i in t])
print(secs)
```

The output is :

```
[[1485072131.170913, 1485072191.170913, 1483344251.170913, 1485072311.170913, 1485072071.170913, 1485072131.170913, 1485072191.170913, 1485072251.170913]]
```

I want the output to be like the inputs (values) shape:

```
[[1485072131.170913, 1485072191.170913, 1483344251.170913, 1485072311.170913], 
[1485072071.170913, 1485072131.170913, 1485072191.170913, 1485072251.170913]]
```

I know I can do a reshape on the result but is there another way to do it when I am appending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make your list comprehension nested rather than flat:

```
secs = [[i.timestamp() for i in t] for t in values]
print(secs)
```

And you'll get what you want:

```
[[1485097331.170913, 1485097391.170913, 1483369451.170913, 1485097511.170913], 
[1485097271.170913, 1485097331.170913, 1485097391.170913, 1485097451.170913]]
```